Kali linux does not update and does not upgrade
Kali Linux has some problems, can you help me in detail to solve these problems? I am using Kali Linux version 2020.2.

I write sudo apt update and sudo apt upgrade, it doesn't update and doesn't upgrade. Reading package list... Done All packages up to date. He gives it as an Output. So there are no updates and upgrades.

I want to download and install virtualbox through the terminal. For this, I type sudo apt install virtualbox or sudo apt install virtualbox -y in Terminal, but it gives an error. Virtualbox-7.0 Debian-bullseye [Not candidate version] E: Package 'virtualbox' has no installation candidate. I'm trying so hard to solve these errors, I'm looking on the internet. But it doesn't work. sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list This file is empty.



Please ask one question at a time. What makes you think the first point is a problem? It tells you everything is up to date. What do you expect differently?

The Kali package virtualbox does exist. Did you disable/Do you not have enabled the corresponding package repository contrib?

Have you enabled networking? Kali ships with networking disabled by default. More importantly, why are you using Kali? Kali is not a normal operating system, it is a professional pentesting tool and shouldn't be used as an operating system. Why would you ever install a VM on a Kali machine? Please read Should I use Kali? from the official Kali docs. Any Linux can do everything Kali can do if you just install a couple of packages, so if you're learning, please use a normal distro.

Don't use Kali if you really know what you're doing

The apt sources are configured alternatively/in combination in /etc/apt/sources.list and list files in the /etc/apt/sources.list.d folder.
If sources.list is empty, make sure your have the package sources you want/intend to have in sources.list.d folder list files.
If all of them are empty, you should restore them to their original content.
